java lambda Transform a map<K, List<MyObject>> to map<K, List<String>>
I need to transform a map:
Map<String, List<Employee>> departmentWiseEmployees
to
Map<String, List<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeNames
...using Java lambda.
Mostly I see a 2nd level stream processing over the Map's entryset.
What would be an elegant way truly leveraging Java stream processing feature?

There's not going to be a more elegant way that doesn't involve streaming over the entry set.  Sorry if you thought there was.

The canonical way is indeed to loop over/stream the entry set of the map:
departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Employee::getName).toList()));

The whole thing becomes easier to read if you extract a method to extract the names of the employees:
departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> names(e.getValue())));

static List<String> names(final Collection<? extends Employee> employees) {
  return employees.stream().map(Employee::getName).toList();
}

Alternatively, a method which accepts a map entry directly makes the stream over the map even more concise:
departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, YourClass::namesOfEmployees);

static List<String> namesOfEmployees(final Map.Entry<?, ? extends Collection<? extends Employee>> entry) {
  return entry.getValue().stream().map(Employee::getName).toList();
}

Of course, both approaches can be combined:
departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, YourClass::namesOfEmployees);

static List<String> namesOfEmployees(final Map.Entry<?, ? extends Collection<? extends Employee>> entry) {
  return names(entry.getValue());
}

static List<String> names(final Collection<? extends Employee> employees) {
  return employees.stream().map(Employee::getName).toList();
}

Going even further, you might want to provide a generic wrapper method instead to apply a method to the value of the map entry:
departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, fromValue(YourClass::names));

static <V, R> Function<Map.Entry<?, ? extends V>, R> fromValue(final Function<? super V, ? extends R> fn) {
  return entry -> fn.apply(entry.getValue());
}

static List<String> names(final Collection<Employee> employees) {
  return employees.stream().map(Employee::getName).toList());
}

(completely untested, I hope I got the generics right)
And ultimately, it's trivial to introduce a top-level method to transform the values of arbitrary maps:
static <K, V, R> Map<K, R> mapValues(
    final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map,
    final Function<? super V, ? extends R> fn) {
  return map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, fromValue(fn)));
}

final Map<String, List<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeNames
    = mapValues(departmentWiseEmployees, employees -> names(employees));
// or with a method ref: mapValues(departmentWiseEmployees, YourClass::names);

Because it was suggested in the comments: If you often have to handle maps with collections as values, it might make sense to create yet another method which doesn't apply a function to the value as a whole, but to each element in the value collection. An overload allows you to collect to different collection types, such as a set (defaults to producing a list):
static <K, V, R> Map<K, List<R>> mapMultiValues(
    final Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> map,
    final Function<? super V, ? extends R> fn) {
  return mapMultiValues(map, fn, Collectors.toList());
}

static <K, V, R, C extends Collection<? extends R>> Map<K, C> mapMultiValues(
    final Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> map,
    final Function<? super V, ? extends R> fn,
    final Collector<R, ?, C> collector) {
  return mapValues(map, values -> values.stream().map(fn).collect(collector));
}

final Map<String, List<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeNames
    = mapMultiValues(departmentWiseEmployees, Employee::getName);

final Map<String, Set<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeDistinctNames
    = mapMultiValues(departmentWiseEmployees, Employee::getName, Collectors.toSet());


such an exhaustive solution coverage! appreciate it!

There’s one option missing, to create another utility method <K, V, R> Map<K, List<R>> mapMultiValues(Map<? extends K, ? extends List<? extends V>> map, Function<? super V, ? extends R> fn) atop mapValues

@Holger maybe even Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> :) And yes, that's certainly possible. Do you think it would improve this answer? If so, I'd happily add it.

Yes, that’s a nice addition.

There is no elegant way to do it completely with stream API, indeed.
You can do for example
    Map<String, List<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeNames = departmentWiseEmployees.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> Map.entry(
                    e.getKey(),
                    e.getValue().stream().map(Employee::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

However I suggest rather something like
    Map<String, List<String>> departmentWiseEmployeeNames = new HashMap<>();
    departmentWiseEmployees.forEach((department, employees) ->
            departmentWiseEmployeeNames.put(department, employees.stream().map(Employee::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    );

Use desired behaviour instead of Employee::toString

The 2nd one is lesser code. looks good
